# How to rename a TFVC repository in Azure DevOps project?

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc

I need to rename a TFVC repository in Azure DevOps project. I do not see the option to [How to rename a TFVC repository in Azure DevOps project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53019184/how-to-rename-a-tfvc-repository-in-azure-devops-project/53021437#do) that:

[image]

For Git repositories, however, there is an option to rename a repository:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TFVC repo follows the name of the Project. By renaming the project the repo should follow.

- Open organisation settings
- Select **General** and then **projects**.
- Select the **...** menu item on the project and choose **Rename**

See also:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/rename-project?view=vsts